# VB.NET Geocoding

Tags: vb.net, geocoding

This code below returns successfully latitude and longitude when address is given. But I want to know how many times it can be used per day. In my application I want to just storage the coordinates in a database and use them in MAP which is not google map. The code below uses url, do I have to implement with webservice and API key? I am confused with the policies and terms of use of the google maps api. If someone could answer these questions I would be thankful.

```
 Dim address = "Κατεχάκη 60, Αθήνα"
        Dim requestUri = String.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0}&sensor=false", Uri.EscapeDataString(address))

        Dim request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri)
        Dim response = request.GetResponse()
        Dim xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream())

        Dim result = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result")
        Dim locationElement = result.Element("geometry").Element("location")
        Dim lat = locationElement.Element("lat")
        Dim lng = locationElement.Element("lng")
```

Comment: What stopped you from just googling that? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

Comment: dont be ironic please or dont answer. yes I have already seen this but I am confused because i hit url and not webservice. But I think it is the same for the usage per day. I just wanted someone more experienced to verify it.

Comment: What I dont get is, if I can use it without google map on an application.

Comment: a) I'm not answering, I'm commenting. b) I'm not ironic. This isn't really a programming related question.

Comment: @vicangel You wrote _I am confused because i hit url and not webservice._ The URL you call **is** the webservice.

Comment: yes but I dont use an api key. Can I really use it to my application that I described? @MatSnow

Comment: yes is dublicate thank you and sorry for the incovenience

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments. You can find usage limits [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits).

For you code, I recommend you add UserAgent Header and some other headers to your request and use **Using** statement for response objects.

```
Dim address = "Κατεχάκη 60, Αθήνα"
Dim requestUri = String.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0}&sensor=false", Uri.EscapeDataString(address))

Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(requestUri)
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate
request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
Using resp As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Using respStrm = resp.GetResponseStream()
        Dim xdoc = XDocument.Load(respStrm)
        Dim result = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result")
        Dim locationElement = result.Element("geometry").Element("location")
        Dim lat = locationElement.Element("lat")
        Dim lng = locationElement.Element("lng")
    End Using
End Using
```